# Understanding The shift operators

Tags: c++

I'm looking over some code that shifts an unsigned integer 32 times but finding it difficult to understand the use of the shift operators in combination with the OR operator.

What exactly is this actually doing when its executed?

Just as an example what would be the outcome if the variables were set to:

```
_arg1 = 1
_arg2 = 20

((_arg1 << _arg2) | (_arg1 >> (32 - _arg2)))
```

If there are easier values for the variables to explain this feel free to change them to better suit your needs.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Write it out. Take pen and paper, start with a byte (8 bits) perhaps, some simple values and then have a look at what it does.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? (BTW your "OR" operator is a bitwise-OR. Maybe that is the source of the confusion.)

Comment: What is >>>? That's not a c++ operator.

Comment: Looks like it it _rotates_ the 32 bit value, so a 1 step left shift of bit 31 ends up in bit 0. Trying it out with pen and paper is not a bad idea.

Comment: Do you understand binary numbers, bitwise operations etc?  If not, you should do some Googling.  Those shift operators are not some massive secret - they are well explained in oodles of sites.

Comment: @juanchopanza Its the OR operator is what is confusing to me. I get how its shifting the bits and all that but what is the OR doing in between?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR

Comment: It is computing the bitwise-OR between the expressions on its LHS and RHS.

Comment: @juanchopanza My apologies, I should have made it more clear of what part I did not understand. As you said it was the bitwise-OR operation that was the source of my confusion. The answer below explained it very well of what was actually happening. Although, Thank you for your comment. It pretty much cleared everything up as soon as I saw "bitwise-OR" operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<< and >> are shift operators, that move the bits of the variable by arg2 positions...

So if you have:

```
11001010 << 2
```

you would move the entire bitstring two to the left. This actually pushes the first two (form the left) bits out of the variable, and from the right side some 0's are pushed in. So:

11001010 << 2 = 00101000

In your question, you are making a rotate shift.

so lets assume arg1 = 11001010 (in binary) and arg2 = 2, and as we use a 8bit integer, we replace the 32 by an 8.

```
((11001010 << 2) | (11001010 >> (8 - 2)))
= (00101000 | 00000011)
```

And now the | connects the two bitstrings to one, so if a bit is set in one string, it will now be also set in the result:

```
(00101000 | 00000011) == 00101011
```

So what is your piece of code actually doing? It is called a circular or rotate shift... The bits it pushes out on one side, it actually pushes in from the other side. So you can rotate the bitpattern around, instead of just shifting one side into nothing and adding zeros on the other side.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the exact explanation I was looking for.  Now I understand how the OR operator played a role in the outcome. I would vote the answer up but I don't have a reputation of 15 yet.

Comment: @user2881275 you can mark it as correct answer, if you like it, just use the checkmark below the voting

Answer (score 1):

This will apply [circular shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift).

Let's take an example:

```
uint32_t _arg1 = 0xc2034000;
uint32_t _arg2 = 2;
```

so binary

```
_arg1 = 11000010000000110100000000000000

_arg2 = 00000000000000000000000000000010
```

### (_arg1 << _arg2)

shifts _arg1 to the left by _arg2 bits, in fact this means take a number created by dropping _arg2 number of bits from _arg1 (starting from left and adding 0 as added values)

```
_arg1 = 11000010000000110100000000000000
        ^^

result is 00001000000011010000000000000000
```

### _arg1 >> (32 - _arg2)

shifts _arg1 to the right by ( 32 - _arg2) bits, in fact this means take a number created by dropping (32 - _arg2) number of bits from _arg1 (starting from the right and adding 0 as added values), so **take those _arg2 bits that were dropped previously**

```
_arg1 = 11000010000000110100000000000000
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

result is 00000000000000000000000000000011
```

### ((_arg1 << _arg2) | (_arg1 >> (32 - _arg2)))

This will concatenate both applying logical OR operation on each two corresponding bits in left and right hand side arguments.

```
((_arg1 << _arg2) | (_arg1 >> (32 - _arg2)))
 result is  00001000000011010000000000000011
```

---

std::bitset can be really helpful for playing with bit sets as you can easily visualize what is going on in your code.

http://ideone.com/jgRvWo

Answer (score 0):

break the statement into small parts, first take (_arg1 << _arg2) which means
1 << 20, now calculate the value if 1 shifted towards left by 20 positions then the binary values looks like 100000000000000000000 (each time 1 is shifted towards left 0 will be filled in the position of 1) which results into 1048576.

Now take the other part, (_arg1 >> (32 - _arg2))) which means
1 >> 12. since 1 is the least positive value so if we move 1 towards right by even one position it will become 0.

Our two parts are done now we will do a bitwise OR of the two results we have got i.e.
    100000000000000000000 | 0

which we will put like

```
100000000000000000000
                    0
```

now we will do OR each bitwise(vertically) of the two values, which will give us 100000000000000000000 whose decimal value is 1048576.
You can refer following table for bitwise OR operations.

```
0 0    = 0
0 1    = 1
1 0    = 1
1 1    = 1
```